# Couchbase: How to copy data from bucket to another?

Tags: couchbase

I have a bucket (`Bucket1`) that I need to delete, and move its documents to another bucket (`Bucket2`).

What is the best way achieving this?

I'm using version 4.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cbtransfer tool should be able to do the data transfer you need.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/cli/cbtransfer-tool.html

bucket-delete can be used to delete a bucket once you are finished with it.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/cli/cbcli/couchbase-cli-bucket-delete.html

Comment: Is it valid for 4.5?

Comment: You can do this with straight N1QL, I believe, too.  Query would be something like `
INSERT INTO target (KEY _k, VALUE _v)
SELECT META().id _k, _v
from default _v`.  See https://blog.couchbase.com/copying-documents-between-buckets-in-couchbase/