# couchbase copy data from seperate network

Tags: python, couchbase

I want to take all data from another bucket.
I already know, there are `cbtransfer, … cbbackup…cbrestore…`and so on.
but each other exists seperate network.
therefore, these can not be solutions.

is there recommended way to get data using python?
and I don’t know all of keyname in bucket. nested key neither.

I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004461/couchbase-how-to-copy-data-from-bucket-to-another).
not helped.

here is my conclusion.

> Is there any way to get data from couchbase bucket using python, without knowing key name?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a [N1QL query from Python](https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html), which can select all documents (though you might want to [page](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/services-and-indexes/indexes/index_pushdowns.html#pagination-pushdown) through it, depending on how much data you want to move).

Alternatively, if you just want to move data from one Couchbase cluster to another, XDCR is exactly what you need. Set up an [XDCR](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/manage-xdcr/xdcr-management-overview.html) connection (you can do so via the UI) from one cluster to the other.

Comment: but there is problem. it returns `Attention: Could not connect to "private IP" on port 8091. This could be due to an incorrect host/port combination or a firewall in place between the servers.` . I guess maybe couchbase has configuration about "allowing IP" somewhere. Am I right?

Comment: I use reverse proxy to retrieve clusters.